# modifyDataType in Liquibase against SQL Server

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to modify the data type on a number of columns from int to bigint using:

```
<modifyDataType tableName="ACCESS_HISTORY" columnName="ID" newDataType="${LongType}"/>
```

Where I have defined LongType to be:

```
<property name="LongType" value="bigint" dbms="mssql"/>
```

I noticed in the Liquibase JIRA (https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1062) that there is a known issue from 2011 relating to the PKs and FKs that need to be dropped. Dropping and re-creating the keys isn't really an option for me.

The error I got was:

```
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedExc
eption: Migration failed for change set ChangeColumnTypes.xml::4-4-060
-2::thof:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL ALTER TA
BLE [dbo].[ACCESS_HISTORY] ALTER COLUMN [ID] BIGINT: The object 'PK_Access_Histo
ry' is dependent on column 'ID'.:
          Caused By: Error executing SQL ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ACCESS_HISTORY] ALTE
```

R COLUMN [ID] BIGINT: The object 'PK_Access_History' is dependent on column 'ID'

I was wondering if anyone had got around this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid to say that there is no way to currently do this unless you drop the PK constraint. It looks like the bug you're talking about though is scheduled to be fixed in version 3 of liquibase, however there is no release date for this version.

Sorry!

As Liquibase is open source you could always fix the bug yourself. :)